# How to check a Value for number

Tags: php

how can i check in PHP a value for a number? What kind is better? Check ctype_digit() for a string automatically?

```
<?php 
if(ctype_digit($value)){
echo 'Yes';
} else {
echo 'No';
}

if(is_string($value) && ctype_digit($value)){
echo 'Yes';
} else {
echo 'No';
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to check if the value is integer or string?

Comment: is_numeric()  you can  use this

Comment: For a string only, i need to use ctype_digit() but  i dont know should i use is_string befor or not?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a variable is a number or a numeric string use [**is_numeric**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function:

```
echo (is_numeric($value))? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gettype() method which returns the variable type as a string, or you can just use is_string(), is_int(), is_float(), is_object(), is_array(), etc. to evaluate if the variable is of a given type.

You can see the full documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php